# c# how to approach Abstract Factory with different signatures (?)

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to create different baddies in a game.

let's say I have 2 factions. Paladins and Thieves, and 3 warrior types for each faction

I have an abstractFactory that generates the equipment they are carrying, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Here is what I have in place

```
enum PaladinWarrior
{
    Squire,
    Novice,
    Knight

}

/// <summary>
/// abstract weapon factory
/// </summary>
abstract class EquipmentFactory
{
    public abstract IWeapon GetWeapon(Enum warriorType);
    /// maybe some other methods like armor and hp
}

/// <summary>
/// concrete weapon factory
/// </summary>
class PaladinWeaponFactory : EquipmentFactory
{
    public override IWeapon GetWeapon(PaladinWarrior warriorType)
    {
        switch (warriorType)
        {
            case PaladinWarrior.Squire:
                return new ShortSword();
            case PaladinWarrior.Novice:
                return new LongSword();
            case PaladinWarrior.Knight:
                return new GreatSword();
            default:
                break;
        }
        
    }
}

/// another factory for the thieves, etc.
```

The problem i am facing is that by specifying the Enum type, it no longer matches the abstract factory, and would not be straight forward to make it work. in other words, the abstract factory's getWeapon doesnt' have the same signature as the Palading one, and i don't know how to approach that.

I am wondering what pattern/workflow would be better for this? considering I have multiple factions and each faction needs different warriors (With different equipment, of course).

Edit: I wanted the Factory so i could Create a warrior like this:

```
Warrior goodGuy = new Warrior(PaladinWarrior.Squire)
Warrior badGuy = new Warrior(ThievesWarrior.BBEV)
```

and have the Warrior class be able to create the armor and equipment. I don't know what other pattern could accomplish that other than a factory.

Comment: Why do you need a factory at all? Why don't you specify the weapon type directly in the entity definition?

Comment: edited the question to respond to the comments

Comment: It is not Abstract Factory, you have a Factory Method (or with different name Virtual Constructor.).
Factory method creates an instance from same concrete family but Abstract factory creates some instances from different families. 

Actually, your classes must have to common behaviours and that behaviour must come from an interface or abstract class.

Comment: IMO this still sounds like you are overly complicating your setup. You should have a single enum for "warrior type" and then a single method that creates and returns the object based on the passed enum value. There is no need for inheritance

Comment: @M.FurkanARDOĞAN I did not understand what you meant at all. the "families" that i have are the paladin and the thief factions.

Comment: Or you might want to go the route that real games take where all your data is specified in external files and your code only reads in that data and puts it into the corresponding classes (which completely decouples adding new warrior types from your code)

Comment: @UnholySheep If you type that last comment into a response, i'll accept it as the answer.

I think i am complicating myself, but that happens when you don't knwo what you're doing, or what the important boundaries are. Thank you for your response.

edit: i know that i should do it reading data from a db, but i just want to learn stuff at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question talks about adding warrior types in a game I will answer from a game development perspective

The approach with different enums and different factories creating the warriors is overly complicated, it would be much simpler to merge the enums and have only a single factory that creates the entire `Warrior` object.

However, in "proper game development" even that is not a good idea, because you want to give the choice of adding and modifying these warrior types to designers, who do not want to (and should not have to) modify code.

Instead you want to make your approach data-driven, which means that all the data necessary to create a `Warrior` is stored externally in a file or database, using a pre-defined format (which can be a common one like JSON or something completely custom). Then all your code has to do is read in that data and create the objects based on it.